# Как вывести последние 500 строк из таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Есть таблица в базе данных Oracle, таблица логов, как можно вывести последние 500 строк. Под словом последние я имею ввиду свежие записи. Или в каком то временном промежутке. Сам запрос у меня такой.

```
select*from FORERRORLOG where BEGINDATE between to_date('15/10/2019','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('15/11/2019','dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Тут я вывожу все, в лягушке (Toad), я бы это отсортировал, но в моем случае надо быстро и коротко.
Сама таблица такая.

```
CREATE TABLE KANCHPROD.FORERRORLOG
(
  BEGINDATE  DATE,
  ENDDATE    DATE,
  MESSAGE    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  ERRCODE    NUMBER
)
TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
MONITORING;

COMMENT ON COLUMN KANCHPROD.FORERRORLOG.BEGINDATE IS 'Дата начала';

COMMENT ON COLUMN KANCHPROD.FORERRORLOG.ENDDATE IS 'Дата конца';

COMMENT ON COLUMN KANCHPROD.FORERRORLOG.MESSAGE IS 'Сообщение';

COMMENT ON COLUMN KANCHPROD.FORERRORLOG.ERRCODE IS 'Код ошибки';
```

Comment: Отсортировать (ORDER BY) в порядке уменьшения штампа времени (ну или что там определяет, какие записи "свежие"), и взять первые 500... а чтобы быстро - индекс надо создать соответствующий.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но индекс увы не создать нужно просто делать выборку.

Comment: Нет индекса - нет "быстро". Чудес, знаешь ли, не бывает.

Comment: Под быстро я имею ввиду просто сделать выборку, 500 строк выбрать это не так долго. Вопрос как мне выбрать свежие.

Comment: *как мне выбрать свежие.* На этот вопрос я УЖЕ ответил. Без сортировки - задача не решается. Даже медленно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions144.htm#SQLRF06100).

```
with T as (
  select
    FORERRORLOG.*,
    row_number() over(order by BEGINDATE desc) as RN
  from FORERRORLOG
  where BEGINDATE >= date'2019-10-15' and
        BEGINDATE < date'2019-11-15'
)
select * from T where RN < 501;
```

Comment: Спасибо , да работает.

Comment: Не за что :) Рассмотрите вариант создания индекса по `BEGINDATE`.